# Selenium X-path Selectors - I need to be able to select the different options in the drop down menu

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, pageobjects

I am new to automations.I have a drop down box with many available selections and want add automation but not sure how to add the with the selectors. I was able to get one selection working but want to add ' **or** the next selection", or the next depending on what the user selects. I hope that made sense, I am not sure If I need to CHAIN the selectors with OR statement or add some type of CHILD elements. All the possible selection in the drop down have the same class just different **TEXT.**

what's the best way to get all the possible dropdowns. I need it for the page object

This works but only selects one..
**get SearchDate()  { return $('//span[contains(text(),"Last 18 months")]'); }**

**Examples**

```
<span class="form__select-custom-option    ">Last 7 days</span>
<span class="form__select-custom-option    ">Last 6 months</span>
<span class="form__select-custom-option    ">Last 30 Days</span>
```

However they all have a different data_test attribute
**Example** of unique attribute for each

```
  data-test="date-range-1"
    data-test="date-range-2"
    data-test="date-range-3"
    data-test="date-range-5"
```

**Last 30 days is what the screen defaults to**

```
<button kdsselecttrigger="" type="button" class="kds-form__select-input" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="date-tran-search choose-a-datetrigger" id="choose-a-datetrigger" aria-describedby="date-range-error">
    <span>Last 30 days</span>
</button>
```

Other selections that the user can select from the drop downmenu one at a time

```
<div class="kds-form__select-custom-menu">
    <div class="kds-form__select-custom-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" id="choose-a-valuedaterangelist" aria-labelledby="date-tran-search" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div data-test="tran-search-date-range-0" class="kds-form__select-custom-item" for="choose-a-valuedaterangelist" role="option" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="kds-form__select-custom-option kds-form__select-custom-option--active   ">Today</span>
        </div>
        <div data-test="tran-search-date-range-1" class="kds-form__select-custom-item" for="choose-a-valuedaterangelist" role="option" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="kds-form__select-custom-option    ">Yesterday</span>
        </div>
        <div data-test="tran-search-date-range-2" class="kds-form__select-custom-item" for="choose-a-valuedaterangelist" role="option" aria-selected="false">
            <span class="kds-form__select-custom-option    ">Last 7 days</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> All the possible selection in the drop down have the same class just different TEXT.

Use the `class` attribute to get all of the `<span>`'s:

```
//span[normalize-space(@class)="form__select-custom-option"]
```

Or, if you want to use the `data-test` attribute, you can use

```
//span[contains(@data-test), "date-range-")]
```

You didn't provide the whole HTML source snippet, so this is kind of speculative.

Comment: I added the code above, I hope you can see it, just started using Stackover flow and now sure how this works :-).... I am trying what you suggested now..................    get transDateValueOlb()  { return $('//*[@class="kds-form__select-custom-option"]')

Comment: I rejected your edit and, instead, added it to your question. There I noticed that the code has already been present, but was invisible due to formatting errors.

Comment: But now, after the code is given, what would look like your desired output?

Comment: It is a drop down menu. when the user clicks on a date, it appears on the screen and is clicked... I have to use gherkin script to create a feature file and the step file. However i wont be able to do the step file without the appropriate selector from all available options.. if that makes sense

Comment: Sorry. I really cannot deduce what you are trying to do. Maybe someone else is able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: its ok!  Thank You. I got it working today.